# Error updating Schema Extension when resource data previously existed but has been deleted

Tags: azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-entra-id

I have three Schema Extensions created with the current app (*app is the owner*) and can update/edit all "except" for one, which I had previously assigned to a resource (user) and added data.

That previous data has been deleted but the problematic Schema Extension is "not" allowing for it to be updated and giving an error:

`"Unhandled exception. Microsoft.Graph.Models.ODataErrors.ODataError: Cannot delete an existing property."`

The two Schema Extensions that will update are using the same code as the one that doesn't work.

`_graphClient.SchemaExtensions[domain_extensionname].PatchAsync(requestBody);`

Only difference is the previously assigned data for the user resource.  The schema extension data no longer exists for the resource and is confirmed by nothing being returned when explicitly specified.

- *What needs to happen to allow that third Schema Extension to be updated?*
- **Is there any type of flush or purge that needs to be done to allow the Schema Extension to be updated?**

Thanks to any gurus out there.  Have done a pretty sophisticated amount of work up until this gotcha.

The two Schema Extensions that will update are using the same code as the one that doesn't work.

`_graphClient.SchemaExtensions[domain_extensionname].PatchAsync(requestBody);`

The difference is the previously assigned data for the user resource.  The schema extension data no longer exists for the resource and is confirmed by nothing being returned when explicitly specified.

I would expect the Schema Extension to be updatable with no resource data no longer belonging to it.

Comment: I'm not able to reproduce the issue. Could you share more code? How do you remove schema extension from user resource? How did you define requestBody for extension update?

Comment: It sounds like there might be a lingering reference to the deleted data causing the issue. Have you tried explicitly removing any associations to the deleted data from the Schema Extension before attempting to update it? That could help resolve the error you're encountering.